# Waiting for Asynchronous function to return data before proceeding

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am calling a asynchronous function which I have created and in its calling code, wants this function to finish and return its results before continuing to process the rest of the code after calling this asynchronous function. Is this possible?

**Example code:**

```
alert('We\'re starting!');
data = calling_asynchronous_function();
window.location.replace(www.google.com);
// 1000 more lines of code that handles data from asynchronous function
```

Below is the method I'm using, but that means I can create a function out of the asynchronous code...

**Current Method:**

```
alert('We\'re starting!');
asynch_function({'parameter1': value1}, function() {
    // 1000 lines of code that handles data from asynchronous function
});
```

For the `current method`, as you can see I cannot turn the code into a reusable function, and have to duplicate the code everywhere if I want to use something simiilar...

Comment: The method you showed is the correct one. I don't see why you can't turn the code into a reusable function.

Comment: Why do you have to rewrite the code? If you put your 1000 lines into a function call, they can be called from anywhere. And current version is the proper way to process something after the asynchronous call has finished - doing waits for the processing to finish is bad. So I am not really sure what your issue is.

Comment: You shouldn't try to make an asynchronous call synchronous, you will get the browser interface to "freeze" while your method is waiting for the synchronous call to return.

Comment: Why not just use a synchronous call instead of forcing the illusion of one?

Comment: The asynchronous function I'm using is actually the Google Maps geocoding function, where u pass an address in and the function returns a GPS coordinate. I want to take that returned coordinate and do some work with it. Throughout my script, I will need to call this Geocoding function many times, and each time the data returned will be processed in 2 steps. The first step will be the same in all cases, the second step will differ

Comment: My idea is if I can have the geocoding function and step 1 of the procesing as my own function, then I will not have to repeat step2 of my code all over my script... this will mess up my code with chunks of 1000 lines of code, especially if I have to call multiple times and have the asynchronous function nested within each other... I wonder if this is normal because this is my first few encounters with async functions